# how to trigger click function for the first link

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, click

I'm very new to javascript and I used this code I found for a menu table for a site. when you click the tabs it shows specific content on the big box to the right based on which tab you click.

When you load the page though, nothing shows in the right box since everything is hidden. I want it so that one tab's content is already "clicked" when you load the page.

```js
$('.linkdetails').hide();

$('.link').click(function() {
     $('.linkdetails').hide();
     $('.linkdetails[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
     width: '200px' }, 300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menucontainer">      
  <div class="left" >
    <a class="link" data-link="first" href="#">TAB 1         </a>
    <br/>
    <a class="link" data-link="second" href="#">TAB 2</a>
    <br/>      
    <a class="link" data-link="third" href="#">TAB 3 </a>
    <br/>   
   </div>
   <div class="content" >
     <div class="linkdetails" data-link="first" > TAB 1 CONTENT</div>
     <div class="linkdetails" data-link="second" >TAB 2 CONTENT</div>
     <div class="linkdetails" data-link="third" >TAB 3 CONTENT</div>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to open the first link every time the page loads?

Comment: @sportzpikachu yes thats correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```js
$('.linkdetails').hide();

$('.link').click(function () {
    $('.linkdetails').hide();
    $('.linkdetails[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
        width: '200px'
    }, 300);
});

$('.linkdetails[data-link=first]').fadeIn({
    width: '200px'
}, 300);
```

You can replace the `data-link=first` with whichever link you want to be opened first, e.g. `data-link=third`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with localStorage. Just have it so that the status of the clicked TAB is saved dynamically, so that, upon loading the page, you can open the tabs that were opened from before. Here is  a link, I'm sure you can figure it out from here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage